# What is the best session save_handler for PHP and why?

Tags: php, sqlite, session, memcached, redis

There are [many ways](http://devzone.zend.com/413/trick-out-your-session-handler/) to save sessions in PHP. To save them into files has some problems -- e.g. it's not a scalable solution. What is the best way to store sessions in PHP? I found out it's very easy to get working saving sessions into SQLite, which is at least more compact than thousands of files, but it seems not many people does it. Why? They don't know about it, they don't matter, or it's not way better than files? Do you have experience with memcached, redis? I have my own server and I am not satisfied with saving sessions into pure simple files.

Thanks for any suggestions!

EDIT: The question is: What is the "best" session save_handler for PHP and why? I am interested in answer, which sums up possibilities and lists some pros&cons for each of them. I quoted "best", because I know it is application dependent, but I am interested in information which approach is best for which types of apps.

Comment: The best is the one that works best for your application. You might want to narrow the question to a particular save handler. Right now, its too broad and generic and will likely be closed. Maybe start by pointing out why you are not satisfied with your current approach and what you are looking for in a solution and answer.

Comment: should not be closed, I think

Comment: @ShaktiSingh Why? This is a good questions.

Comment: @Shakti how are we supposed to answer whether people know whether they can use Sqlite? Did you ask people? Which? What value is in answering "no, i didnt know", "yes, i use sqlite", "yes, i have experience with redis" or "no, i dont have experience with memcache"?

Comment: [Regarding scalability](http://teddziuba.com/2008/04/im-going-to-scale-my-foot-up-y.html).

Answer (score 2):

Its better not to store sessions in files to avoid scalability problems. I would suggest to use database for storing the sessions. Frameworks like Zend, Symfony, etc provides the facility to store them in database.

Comment: This depends entirely on your setup. Putting session files on a Ram Drive will likely outperform any Session in a remote database connected over a slow network.